Changing nested markup with getElementsByClassName
I'm working with the API of Google's Programmable Search Engine and using a callback to chnage the stying of output, specificaly the font size of the title of each search result snippet.
What I have below works and changes the gs-title font size to 24px. But the problem is that some gs-title divs have the search term inside <b> and </b> tags, and so that the title is rendered at 24px, but inside the bold tags, the font is the original size. See the image below with the search term "test".
Area culinary students <b>test</b> their kitchen skills in 'Chopped' cooking ...


How can I also apply fontSize to text inside the bold tags?
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jqh4ntdv/
SearchResultsRenderedCallback = function(){

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('gs-title');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var element = elements[i];
  element.style.fontSize = "24px";
}

};

window.__gcse || (window.__gcse = {});
window.__gcse.searchCallbacks = {
  web: {
      rendered: SearchResultsRenderedCallback,
  },
};


Please [edit] your question to include the relevant html.

Please [edit] your question to include the code as text, preferably a runnable Stack Snippet. Links can break, leaving them useless to future readers.  Regardless, your html doesn't include any elements with class="gs-title" See How to Ask

You can apply the same styling to the children of an HTML element by using the children property:
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('gs-title');
  for (const element of elements) {
    element.style.fontSize = "24px";
      for (const child of element.children) {
        child.style.fontSize = "24px";
      }
  }


Well, in real life (not on the Fiddle) I get Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let elements Previously declared. Any ideas?

That means that you already declared a variable "elements" in the same scope. Your variables should be uniquely named. You can use the same names if the scopes are separate (f. ex. different functions).

Ah, you're right; my mistake. Works now.
